# "Input not Supported" on external monitor

Tags: laptop, external-display

when it rains, it pours! Im helping a friend with his Dell Inspiron 1520.  The hdd crashed and and top of that, the screen is cracked.  I've replaced the hdd (SATA-5400), but the lcd replacement is only comin in a months time. I've tried to:

1. hook the laptop up to an Acer 18.5" lcd monitor via VGA,
2. boot up into Windows 7 installer,
3. get to the Step-1 screen,
4. Switch to external display (Function-F8)

...and get the "Input not supported" message on the Acer lcd.  I know that this is a resolution problem, but cant for the life of me figure out how to solve this. I've also tried, hooking it up to my TV via Composite cables (got a VGA-Composite adaptor).

Please could someone advise me what to do? -Thank u!

Comment: If you have an old CRT monitor somewhere, those things can usually display just about any resolution, though it may be difficult to read.

Alternatively, try a different LCD. Some are much more forgiving about their input.

Comment: I've tried just about evry display device I can get my hands on! But thanks for the CRT monitor suggestion - now I just need to find one! :)
I'll post back here when I come up with something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to boot the machine into Windows with a lower resolution you want to [enable VGA mode](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/chsafe.htm) to reduce the resolution. If you are having problems during the installation check to see if there are any [other output displays](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7repair/thread/c69206ae-14c7-47d2-a44b-7fadf179ad9a) connected.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem when trying to reinstall Windows on a Gateway laptop hooked to a monitor with the VGA connector. The laptop's original screen is broken.

I was able to get it to display properly by pressing the <kbd>F4</kbd> key used to switch between the laptop's screen and a display connected to the VGA port. After a few times the laptop adjusted to the monitor's resolution.